# Using ES6, how do I return at the end of a for loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, immutability

I am fairly new to Redux, es6, functional programming, and immutability. Since I am using all of these I am having some major confusion in the redux app I am trying to build. The problem I am having is I am trying to update my store, but it is only updating the first element from my action payload array. I know this is due to me doing the return inside of the for in loop. Problem is, I do not know how to return the updated state outside of the for loop.

This is how my reducer looks:

```
function fruitsReducer(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'DEDUCT':
    //only updates one
    for(var actionID in action.payload){
      const actionFruit = action.payload[actionID];
      return {
        ...state,
        fruits: {
          ...state.fruits,
          [actionID]:{
            ...state.fruits[actionID],
            quantityRemaining: state.fruits[actionID].quantityRemaining - actionFruit.deduct
          }
        }
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Here is my dispatch:

```
dispatch({
  type: "DEDUCT", 
  payload: {
    0: {
      "itemName": "banana",
      "deduct": 1
    },
    1: {
      "itemName": "apple",
      "deduct": 1
    },
    5: {
      "itemName": "strawberries",
      "deduct": 1
    }
  }
})
```

Here is my Store:

```
{
  fruits: [
    {
      "itemName": "banana",
      "index": 0,
      "quantityRemaining": 10
    },
    {
      "itemName": "apple",
      "index": 1,
      "quantityRemaining": 5
    },
    {
      "itemName": "raspberry",
      "index": 2,
      "quantityRemaining": 2
    },
    {
      "itemName": "kiwi",
      "index": 3,
      "quantityRemaining": 15
    },
    {
      "itemName": "pineapple",
      "index": 4,
      "quantityRemaining": 1
    },
    {
      "itemName": "strawberries",
      "index": 5,
      "quantityRemaining": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `for in` loop, you probably want to `map` your results and spread the resulting array on top of the current state. I rewrote your reducer to map each action id in the payload. Notice how we are spreading the result of the map after spreading `state.fruits`.

```
function fruitsReducer (state = initialState, action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'DEDUCT':
      return {
        ...state,
        fruits: [
          ...state.fruits.filter((fruit) => {
            return !Object.keys(action.payload).includes(fruit.index);
          }),
          ...Object.keys(action.payload).map((actionId) => {
              const fruit = action.payload[actionId];

              return {
                [actionId]: {
                  ...state.fruits[actionId],
                  quantityRemaining: state.fruits[actionId].quantityRemaining - fruit.deduct
                }
              }
            })
          ]
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

#### Note:

You can also define a sub reducer for each one of the items. A good example would be [@gaeron's todos code](https://github.com/gaearon/todos/blob/master/src/reducers/todos.js).

Comment: when I tried to follow your example. 3 more elements were appended to State.fruits, instead of updating the appropriate elements. Here is what my redux dev tools returned: [State](http://imgur.com/a/EQVOO)

Comment: I updated the first state spread. Like I said, I would go for a sub reducer though for each one of the updates here is a good [explanation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#correct-approach-copying-all-levels-of-nested-data). It makes for an ugly reducer having to filter and spread like this.